# Tevila :How to bring to mikva water urn

Tags: shabbat, water

How do you tovel a shabbes coffee urn without damaging it

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yves and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Many hold that if it’s going to be damaged in the process then it does not need to be toveled. That being said, many people including myself have been able to do it as normal and let it dry for a few days before use. It would depend on the specific unit itself

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  See in particular the focus on sourcing your answers since we don't know you personally and don't know how much credibility to attach to your answers otherwise. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @mbloch Thanks. I’ve browsed here before but never engaged in commenting. Thanks for the links. For what it’s worth my bubby thinks I’m pretty incredible.

Comment: He he he. This is a great start. When you are done with the tour see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site and its difference with others. We value new contributors esp. when they have strong Torah knowledge and their bubbies love them